# Swift & Objective-c use AFNetwork crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, afnetworking

Where the data is requested, occasionally crashes.
I don't know if is the AFNetworking's problem or my code's problem.

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(__unused id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if (context == AFHTTPRequestSerializerObserverContext) {
        if ([change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
            [self.mutableObservedChangedKeyPaths removeObject:keyPath];
        } else {
            [self.mutableObservedChangedKeyPaths addObject:keyPath];
        }
    }
}
```

[image: list]